# What is wrong with this mysql statement - INSERT INTO ... WHERE ... OR?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my mysql statement but for some reason it isn't actually working and I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance!

```
$ID = $_GET['post'];
$length = $_POST['excerpt_length'];

more code here to connect and select db...

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO wp_posts (excerpt)
VALUES(" . $length . ")
WHERE ID = " . $ID . "
OR post_name LIKE '" . $ID . "%'");
```

This is for wordpress and I'm making an option to add an excerpt length because as far as I am aware, there isn't any yet. Thanks!

Ethan Brouwer

Comment: There's no `WHERE` needed in `INSERT INTO` because it will be appended  at the end anyway. Just leave it out

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection, read this thread to learn how to prevent it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use where in insert into because you are supposed to create a new record, there is no referenced to look for. You must use Update instead.

```
mysql_query("
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET excerpt = '" . $length . "'
WHERE ID = '" . $ID . "'
OR post_name LIKE '" . $ID . "%'");
```

Comment: Thank You! I found it on Yahoo just a couple minutes later but thanks. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have an ID, and you want to keep the ID as it is, use an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT ...` inserts a new row into the table. It has no `WHERE` clause.
If you want to update an existing row, use an `UPDATE ...` statement.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan points out your syntax is incorrect. If you want to limit the excerpt length in WordPress you can use filters. Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-excerpt-length-by-characters).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked, but I wouldn't think you can use an OR-statement in an INSERT-query. Maybe do another query before this one to find out an id to insert to..?